# Send text from Models to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm designing a C# / WPF application, and trying to adhere to MVVM (but I don't mind taking shortcuts, as I'm quite a beginner).

I have a ViewModel and several Models. In the View there is a TextBox that is meant to log messages  about what is happening in the models. The text of the TextBox is already bound to a string property in my ViewModel, but how can I give my Models the ability to append text to that TextBox without breaking the MVVM concept too much?

I was thinking about using Trace and a Trace listener for my TextBox. Is there any other (simple) way?

Thanks

Comment: Why would your models what to alter a property in the ViewModel? Update the property in your viewmodel when whatever code that alter the models runs.

Comment: The model has methods that do things, such as syncing. One of my models is like a network client. Should I move the methods of the model to the viewmodel and only keep data in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put functionality like networking in your model, it's not a model anymore. It will have to many responsibilities and will violate the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Reduce your models to contain only logic tied with the model class itself. Move functionality like networking into service classes.

1. **Update is result of user action in the same ViewModel**

   Call service classes from ViewModel (i.e. in commands representing user actions) and if the call is successful, get the updated value.
2. **Update action happens in another ViewModel or somewhere else (timer/polling)**

   If the sync happens somewhere else, use [EventAggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html). Your service can fire an event/message, your ViewModel will subscribe to it. When receiving this event, update your ViewModel and rise `PropertyChanged`.